# How to pass an unknown type as a function parameter in NXC?

Tags: nxc

I was trying to do it as in a regular C, with void*, but it didn't work. Is it possible to pass it in NXC? If it is- how to do it?

Comment: What exactly did you try and what was the error?

Comment: Like this: "int foo(void *lv, void *rv){ ... }". I took it from here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/318113-passing-unknown-type-as-function-parameters/ ,   from jjl example.
The following errors were shown: "Unknown datatype", "Unexpected character encountered" and "Variable name expected."

Comment: You may be able to use `variant` instead of `void *` (or `variant *`), although to be honest I've not got any experience with BrixCC/NXC.

Comment: Yeah, I tryed the `variant` but there was no result. Seems, that they jast don't have it in NXC. But thank you anyway.